# Threads Join() method output?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to understand how `join()` actually works in `Thread`.

In the below code when I am using only `ft.join()` the output is corrected what we expected:

> 1111122222

but when I am commenting `ft.join()` and using only `st.join()` I am getting output as:

> 1212121212

I thought that output will be:

> 1222221111

How am I still getting output *"1212121212"* while using `st.join()`?

```
class FT extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("1");
            try {
                FT.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class ST extends Thread {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("2");
        try {
            FT.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FT ft = new FT();
        ST st = new ST();
        ft.start();
        //ft.join();
        st.start();
        st.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Test again, and also test with no join.  The position of where you `join`d with `ft.join` is very  very relevant.

Comment: Scary Wombat@ I tried it multiple time when I am using only st.join(), the output is (1212121212) or (2121212121),  I don't whether it i s right or wrong, I was thinking the output will be like (1222221111) as after entering into st thread, I am using st.join() so the st thread will complete its execution before switching to ft thread back.

Comment: No, `join` does not prevent other threads from running concurrently, it will just wait for the thread to `die` before continuing with the next line of code.  The next line of code after `st.join` is to quit the program, so no use at all.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect *"1222221111"* ... the `ft` doesn't care if the main thread joins and waits for `st`. And the main thread also doesn't "switch back" to `ft`, as the main thread doesn't do any switching.

Answer (score 2):

What join does is to what for the joined thread to finish.

So ...

```
ft.start();
ft.join();
st.start();
st.join();
```

will wait for the FT thread to finish before starting the ST thread, but ...

```
ft.start();
// ft.join();
st.start();
st.join();
```

... will start the FT thread and then immediately start the ST thread.

---

About the second case you say:

> I am getting output as (1212121212), I thought that output will be (1222221111). What I was thinking is right or wrong ?

Your thinking is wrong.  In the second case you have two free-running threads that are each printing, sleeping, printing, sleeping and so on.  Since they are not synchronizing with each other, neither thread explicitly waits for the other one.  However, the timing is such that they are (fortuitously) interleaving their respective `print` statements.

Note that this behavior is NOT guaranteed.  If the system was heavily loaded, one thread could "overtake" the other one due to unfair scheduler behavior, and they would not interleave exactly like that.

The `st.join()` and `ft.join()` calls cause "this" thread (i.e. the "main" thread) to wait for the ST thread or FT thread respectively.  They do not cause ST to wait for FT ... or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In jdk8, the official doc explains this function as follow:

> public final void join()
>                   throws InterruptedException
>
> Waits for this thread to die.

It means that the current thread will wait for the new thread till the new one died.
In your code, join() notify the main thread waits for FT/ST thread till they died. 
When you "commenting `ft.join()` and using only `st.join()`", it means that main thread will not wait for `ft`, but will wait for `st`. And there is no relationship or waiting seq between `ft` and `st`.